# How to create channel on youtube to upload videos and is it possible to create channel programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, video, youtube-data-api, youtube-channels

I am using https://github.com/youtube/yt-direct-lite-iOS sample to upload videos.

But the problem is that without having channel we can not upload video on youtube... New User have to setup channel first.. I want this in my app to create channel after user login( if user has no channel in its account).

When user accept the application authentication then i want to hit this url https://www.youtube.com/create_channel.

and let me know if it is possible to create channel programmatically.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** You might want to use [YouTube Data API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/create-channel).

This supports all possible user features for users in YouTube. In your case that it needs creation/uploading, you will use a SSO Method also supported by the YouTube API.

Cheers!

Comment: thanks for your answer. But i am looking for sample to implement it. I am new to iOS development. Its hard to develop for me... Could you upload the sample for it?? thanks in advance!!! @Mark Dominick Flores

Comment: @SourabhSharma  [Here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/libraries) are some of the implementations given by google. you can also use the client library or you can also do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Went into details and did more reading on this. It seems that you cannot create a channel programatically in iOS or Android. Refer to https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/1646861?hl=en
 wherein it has been clarified in Google support.

It also shows how to create channels which answers the first part of your question.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://developers.google.com/youtube/create-channel) might help you. It mentions how to create a channel.

Comment: thanks for your answer. But i am looking for sample to implement it. I am new to iOS development. Its hard to develop for me... Could you upload the sample for it?? thanks in advance!!! @ uchiha